# Is there any (etymological) link between "affection" and "affectation"?

Tags: etymology, nouns

Is there any link between *affection* and *affectation*, especially in terms of etymology?
I understand *-fect* means something like "make". Does "make" play any role in conveying their distinct meanings?

Answer (score 1):

The word affectation has roots going back to a Latin verb *affectare* for "to strive for, or pretend" and had a meaning in rhetoric no very unlike the modern one of trying too hard. Affection goes back to Latin *afficere*, meaning "to have an effect on." (The transition from influence to feeling occurred when being passed through French and Middle English.) *Affectare* derives from *affectus*, past participle of "afficere," so yes.